# "assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast" in c

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, compiler-warnings, dynamic-memory-allocation, gcc-warning

I'm in the late stages of a c program that is a dynamic word search.  I get the "warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]" when I compile these lines:

```
**grid = gridReal;
**items = itemsReal;
**solution = solutionReal;
```

My main up to that point looks like this:

```
int main()
{
char gridReal[50][50];/*Array to hold puzzle*/
char itemsReal[100][50];/*Array to hold words*/
char solutionReal[50][50];/*Array to hold solution*/
int dimension;/*Width and height*/
int x, y;/*Counters for printing*/

char** grid = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char)*100*50);
char** items = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char)*100*50);
char** solution = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char)*100*50);

**grid = gridReal;
**items = itemsReal;
**solution = solutionReal;
```

Any ideas on how to sort this out?

Comment: `**grid` is of type `char`, you are trying to assign a `char (*)[50]` (the type to which `gridReal` decays). Obviously, it won't compile. What are you trying to achieve with these assignments?

Comment: You can't copy arrays using the `=` operator in C, and you haven't initialized them anyway. If you're just trying to assign the address of the array to your pointers, why are you doing all those `malloc()`s and throwing your references away?

Comment: Why are you allocating those three areas twice?   The declaration `char gridReal[50][50]` creates the space.  Calling malloc again and then an assignment to grid is odd....

Comment: Don't use casts, when you obviously not know what you are doing. Compiler diagnostics are there for a reason.

Comment: Ok.  Any suggestion then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you want to copy the memory from e.g. `gridReal` to `grid`. First of all, you have to remember that a pointer to pointer to some type is ***not*** the same as an array or arrays of the same type. The memory layout is simply not compatible. Secondly, you can't simply assign an array to a pointer like that, and expect the data to be copied.

Instead you allocate the outer "dimension" first, then in a loop allocate (and copy) the second "dimension":

```
char **grid = malloc(50));

for (int i = 0; i < 50; ++i)
{
    grid[i] = malloc(sizeof(gridReal[0]);
    memcpy(grid[i], gridReal[i], sizeof(gridReal[i]));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`**grid` is of type `char`. You can't assign `gridReal`, which is of type `char (*)[50]` after decay , to `**grid`. Always remember that **arrays are not pointers**. A pointer to pointer doesn't mean a 2D array.

Comment: Actually, after decaying, `gridReal` is of type `char (*)[50]`.

Comment: @FilipeGonçalves; Correct. I missed that.

Comment: Thanks so far guys.
Was able to type cast to get rid of the warnings:

    grid = (char**)gridReal;
    items = (char**)itemsReal;
    solution = (char**)solutionReal;

So now it's on to clearing up a seg fault..

Comment: So your solution is to use an ugly cast to cheat on the compiler? If this is how you fix your code, I'm not surprised you're having a segfault.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not very good sir.  Any ideas instead of the casting?